# Why special characters are coming in file?

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have following configuration file ,
1)Picking file and sending the contents to active mq.
2)Receiving from active mq and writing it to file
 But once it is written i am getting some special characters in file like 
"¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   ur [B¬óøTà  xp  `".

Why is it coming?

```
<mule>
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="activemqFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\mule\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <set-property propertyName="fileName" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="Property"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="logfilequeue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>
<flow name="JmsInboundFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="logfilequeue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:client-ack-transaction acti on="NONE"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="#[payload.toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\mule\output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.fileName]"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use    `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` after File inbound endpoint like the following :-

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="activemqFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\mule\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <set-property propertyName="fileName" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="Property"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="logfilequeue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>
<flow name="JmsInboundFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="logfilequeue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:client-ack-transaction acti on="NONE"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="#[payload.toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\mule\output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.fileName]"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked , but why it was giving special character?

Comment: This is because the payload after the file is `FileInputStream` which you are getting at the end, but adding the `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` transform the payload into string.